# C++ implementing callback functions

Tags: c++

I know this question has been discussed many other times but it seems I can find an answer that I can fully understand.

My Question is how to pass a member function to a second class as a callback in CPP and without using boost library.

I keep encountering Api calls where callback logic is implemented like this. 
entity.func(MyClass::somemethod, this);

and I'd like to use this kind of notation;

----------------------------DeviceHub Class-------------------------

`DeviceHub` instantiates n `VirtualDevice`s that requires a `DeviceHub` method to be passed as callback so that the `VirtualDevice` object can notify the `DeviceHub` object.

```
class DeviceHub{
  public: 
  DeviceHub(int n);
  virtual ~DeviceHub();

  int virtualDeviceCallback(std::string s);

  std::vector<VirtualDevice> virtual_devices;
}

DeviceHub::DeviceHub(int n){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     VirtualDevice vd = VirtualDevice(...,this); //pass callback method and context
     virtual_devices.push_back(vd);
  }
}

 DeviceHub::virtualDeviceCallback(std::string s){
  /*do something...*/
 }
```

----------------------------VirtualDevice Class-------------------------

```
class VirtualDevice{

  public: 

  VirtualDevice(callbackmethod, context);
  virtual ~VirtualDevice();
  int id;
}

VirtualDevice::VirtualDevice(callbackmethod, context){
    //do something
    //than fire callback
    //context.callbackmethod("some string");
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a Lambda? Wrap the method call in a Lambda before passing it.

Comment: thats what I'm doing right now but I keep encountering api where I can call function like  entity.somefuc(MyClass::somemethod, this) I was wondering how its done.

Comment: Why didn't you ask that then?

Comment: `Somemethod` is a static method. It is like an ordinary `c` callback.

Comment: actually its not that's the reason this is passed along

Comment: @Gavello Post real code please when asking. What you show won't compile properly.

Comment: @Gavello I was talking about your previous comment: `entity.somefuc(MyClass::somemethod, this)`. The simplest way to define a c++ callback is to define a static method `static void myclass::static_fun( myclass* This )`, for instance.

Comment: I would have liked to see this answered.  The one marked as this one's forebear is totally unhelpful.  This asker is more clear.